# Is there any possible way I could use font awesome icons in my electron app in offline mode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, font-awesome

I currently am using font awesome in my electron app but when i dont have wifi it wont load. My current line which i use in html is

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/de******0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Is there any way I could use font awesome icons in my electron app in offline mode
Perhaps like downloading font awesome
Ive downloaded it but I dont know how to load it into my html

Comment: Simply download the kit from fontawesome official website and use it

Comment: Yes ur right I've already did it but it works only when I have wifi available no in offline mode